# Qt 5.2 - How to add a text link into a UI

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, hyperlink

I'll preface this by saying I have a feeling this is probably pretty simple, but I've never done anything like this before and I'm having trouble finding how to do it in the docs. I have a UI in my code, and I need to have a string of text display on the UI as a hyperlink. I couldn't find a specific object type for a hyperlink, so I tried creating a QLabel with the text `<a href="http://www.thesiteIwanttolinkto.com">My link text</a>`. I have the QLabel's textFormat set  to Rich Text (I also tried Auto Text), and under textInteractionFlags I checked LinksAccessibleByMouse. Right now it displays as a hyperlink, but when I click on it nothing happens. Is there a way to get this link to work, either with the QLabel or another way? Also it's probably worth noting, I would like the site being linked to to open in a browser, not a QWebView or anything like that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like I can never find the answer to these questions until right *after* I post it... anyway I just figured it out, under the QLabel properties I forgot to check the box for openExternalLinks. Once I did that it worked fine. Figure I'll leave this up in case anyone has this problem in the future.

Comment: This option is only a shorthand for manually handling the `linkActivated(QString)` signal and in the slot executing `QDesktopServices::openUrl(url)`. It's not on by default because you typically have not only HTTP urls but maybe also application-internal links, i.e. links you handle manually in some way (like a button).